Problem about the number of cycles of a graph of minimal degree $k$

Let $G$ be a graph such that $\delta(G)=k\geq2$. Prove that there exist at least two vertices such that each of them is in at least $\binom{k}{2}$ cycles

I can assume that, without loss of generality, G is connected. I could suppose that $\forall v\in V(G)\quad \nexists v_1,...,v_l\in N(v)\quad (l\geq k)$ such that for each unordered couple $\{v_m,v_n\}$ from $\{v_1,...,v_l\}$ $v,v_m$ and $v_n$ are not in any cycle (or exists at most one vertex with the desired propriety).
However, I am unable to fully grasp all the information that my idea leads to, and steer myself toward a contradiction. Could someone help me untangle this mess, with any hint

Your idea can lead to the goal if we reason according to the following scheme.
Let $G$ be a graph with condition $\delta(G)=k\geq2$.
Take the longest simple path $P$ in $G$. Let $u$ and $v$ be the beginning and the end of $P$.

All neighbours of vertices $u$ and $v$ lie in $P$ (why?).
Let $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ be the neighbours of $u$ occurring on the path $P$ in this order.
For any two neighbours $u_i$ and $u_j$, $i<j$, there exists a cycle containing $u$, $u_i$ and $u_j$: $uu_i\ldots u_ju$ (what is in place of the dots?).
All cycles from (3) are distinct.
The same can be done for vertex $v$.

